# NullPointerException Java - Where should I create these variables?

Tags: java, windows, nullpointerexception

This is a pretty basic question, but I think I'm burned out from looking at code all day.

In the class GUIMainEvent, I had all the references to objects from the other classes hard coded each time i.e. every reference to the radio button from customer screen was gui.customerScreen.rdbtnOneWay.

I created variables in my GUIMainEvent so it would look better and be easier to read and modify, however now I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at projFlight.GUIMainEvent.<init>(GUIMainEvent.java:36)
    at projFlight.GUIMain.<init>(GUIMain.java:25)
    at projFlight.GUIMain.main(GUIMain.java:35)
```

This refers to the first variable I've tried to create, but I know it will happen to each one.

Where can I declare these variables to avoid this? I thought gui.frame existed where I assigned the value. Thanks for looking.

```
package projFlight;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class GUIMain {

    GUIMainEvent event = new GUIMainEvent(this);

    JFrame frame;
    GUILoginScreen login = new GUILoginScreen();
    GUICustomerScreen customerScreen = new GUICustomerScreen();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUIMain window = new GUIMain();
        window.frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public GUIMain() {
        setLookAndFeel();
        initialize();
        controller.start();
    }

    // The thread controlling changes of panels in the main window.
    private Thread controller = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    frame.getContentPane().add(login);
                    addLogo(login);
                    frame.revalidate();

                }
            });

        }
    };

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 406, 473);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        login.btnOk.addActionListener(event);
        login.btnCancel.addActionListener(event);
        customerScreen.rdbtnOneWay.addActionListener(event);
        customerScreen.rdbtnReturnsecondLeg.addActionListener(event);
        customerScreen.cboDeptLeg1.addActionListener(event);
        customerScreen.cboDestLeg1.addActionListener(event);
        customerScreen.cboSeatType.addActionListener(event);
        customerScreen.cboDeptLeg2.addActionListener(event);
        customerScreen.cboDestLeg2.addActionListener(event);
        customerScreen.chkbxInsurance.addActionListener(event);
        customerScreen.btnBookFlights.addActionListener(event);
        customerScreen.btnClear.addActionListener(event);
        customerScreen.btnLogout.addActionListener(event);

    }

    public void addLogo(JPanel panel) {
        BufferedImage myPicture = null;
        try {
            myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Phil\\workspace\\projFlight\\Pictures\\WolfLogo.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
        picLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 170, 128);
        panel.add(picLabel);

    }

    // method to set the look and feel of the GUI
    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            // ignore error
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
package projFlight;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class GUILoginScreen extends JPanel {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JTextField tboUsername;
    JPasswordField passwordField;
    JButton btnOk;
    JButton btnCancel;

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public GUILoginScreen() {
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        setLayout(null);
        setLookAndFeel();

        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username");
        lblUsername.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Black", Font.ITALIC, 18));
        lblUsername.setBounds(77, 170, 109, 35);
        add(lblUsername);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
        lblPassword.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Black", Font.ITALIC, 18));
        lblPassword.setBounds(77, 235, 109, 35);
        add(lblPassword);

        tboUsername = new JTextField();
        tboUsername.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Black", Font.ITALIC, 18));
        tboUsername.setBounds(77, 203, 241, 31);
        add(tboUsername);
        tboUsername.setColumns(10);

        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        passwordField.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Black", Font.ITALIC, 18));
        passwordField.setBounds(77, 268, 241, 31);
        add(passwordField);

        btnOk = new JButton("OK");
        btnOk.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Black", Font.ITALIC, 18));
        btnOk.setBounds(77, 349, 109, 35);
        add(btnOk);

        btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Black", Font.ITALIC, 18));
        btnCancel.setBounds(209, 349, 109, 35);
        add(btnCancel);

    }

    // method to set the look and feel of the GUI
    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            // ignore error
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
/**
 * 
 */
package projFlight;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

/**
 * @author Phil
 *
 */
public class GUIMainEvent implements ActionListener {

    ArrayList<String> airportList = new ArrayList<String>();

    GUIMain gui;

    GUIMainEvent(GUIMain in) {
        gui = in;
        airportList.add("Dublin");
        airportList.add("Sligo");
        airportList.add("Luton");
    }

    JFrame mainGUI = gui.frame;
    GUICustomerScreen customerScreenGUI = gui.customerScreen;
    GUILoginScreen loginGUI = gui.login;
    JButton btnLoginOk = gui.login.btnOk;
    JButton btnLoginCancel = gui.login.btnCancel;
    JRadioButton rdbtnCustomerOneWay = gui.customerScreen.rdbtnOneWay;
    JRadioButton rdbtnCustomerReturn = gui.customerScreen.rdbtnReturnsecondLeg;
    JComboBox cboCustomerDeptLeg1 = gui.customerScreen.cboDeptLeg1;
    JComboBox cboCustomerDestLeg1 = gui.customerScreen.cboDestLeg1;
    JComboBox cboCustomerDeptLeg2 = gui.customerScreen.cboDeptLeg2;
    JComboBox cboCustomerDestLeg2 = gui.customerScreen.cboDestLeg2;
    JLabel lblCustomerDeptLeg2 = gui.customerScreen.lblDeptLeg2;
    JLabel lblCustomerDestLeg2 = gui.customerScreen.lblDestLeg2;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Object source = event.getSource();

        if (source == btnLoginOk) {

            mainGUI.getContentPane().remove(loginGUI);
            mainGUI.repaint();
            mainGUI.getContentPane().add(customerScreenGUI);
            gui.addLogo(customerScreenGUI);
            customerScreenGUI.setVisible(true);
            mainGUI.repaint();
            mainGUI.revalidate();

        } else if (source == btnLoginCancel) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (source == rdbtnCustomerOneWay) {
            if (rdbtnCustomerOneWay.isSelected()) {
                disableLeg2();
            }
        } else if (source == rdbtnCustomerReturn) {
            if (rdbtnCustomerReturn.isSelected()) {
                enableLeg2();
            }
        } else if (source == cboCustomerDeptLeg1) {
            updateDestLeg1();
        } else if (source == cboCustomerDestLeg1) {
            if (!rdbtnCustomerOneWay.isSelected()) {
                updateDeptLeg2();
            }
        } else if (source == cboCustomerDeptLeg2) {
            if (!rdbtnCustomerOneWay.isSelected()) {
                updateDestLeg2();
            }
        } else if (source == gui.customerScreen.btnBookFlights) {
            bookFlights();
        } else if (source == gui.customerScreen.btnClear) {
            clearAll();
        } else if (source == gui.customerScreen.btnLogout) {
            logout();
        }
    }

    private void logout() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void clearAll() {
        cboCustomerDeptLeg1.setSelectedIndex(0);
        cboCustomerDestLeg1.removeAllItems();
        cboCustomerDeptLeg2.removeAllItems();
        cboCustomerDestLeg2.removeAllItems();

    }

    private void bookFlights() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void updateDestLeg2() {
        JComboBox from = cboCustomerDeptLeg2;
        JComboBox to = cboCustomerDestLeg2;
        if (from.getSelectedItem() != null) {
            to.removeAllItems();
            for (int i = 0; i < cboCustomerDeptLeg1.getItemCount(); i++) {
                if (cboCustomerDeptLeg1.getItemAt(i).toString().equals(gui.customerScreen.defaultItem)) {
                    continue;
                } else if (!(from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(cboCustomerDeptLeg1.getItemAt(i).toString()))) {
                    to.addItem(cboCustomerDeptLeg1.getItemAt(i));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void updateDeptLeg2() {
        JComboBox from = cboCustomerDestLeg1;
        JComboBox to = cboCustomerDeptLeg2;
        if (from.getSelectedItem() != null) {
            to.removeAllItems();
            to.addItem(from.getSelectedItem());
        }

    }

    private void updateDestLeg1() {

        JComboBox from = cboCustomerDeptLeg1;
        JComboBox to = cboCustomerDestLeg1;
        if (from.getSelectedItem() != null) {

            to.removeAllItems();
            for (int i = 0; i < from.getItemCount(); i++) {
                if (from.getItemAt(i).toString().equals(gui.customerScreen.defaultItem)) {
                    continue;
                } else if (!(from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(from.getItemAt(i).toString()))) {
                    to.addItem(from.getItemAt(i));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void enableLeg2() {
        updateDeptLeg2();
        updateDestLeg2();
        lblCustomerDeptLeg2.setEnabled(true);
        lblCustomerDestLeg2.setEnabled(true);
        cboCustomerDeptLeg2.setEnabled(true);
        cboCustomerDestLeg2.setEnabled(true);

    }

    private void disableLeg2() {
        cboCustomerDeptLeg2.removeAllItems();
        cboCustomerDestLeg2.removeAllItems();
        lblCustomerDeptLeg2.setEnabled(false);
        lblCustomerDestLeg2.setEnabled(false);
        cboCustomerDeptLeg2.setEnabled(false);
        cboCustomerDestLeg2.setEnabled(false);

    }

}
```

---

```
package projFlight;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class GUICustomerScreen extends JPanel {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */

    String firstName = "Philip";
    String lastName = "Woulfe";
    JRadioButton rdbtnOneWay;
    JRadioButton rdbtnReturnsecondLeg;
    ButtonGroup group;
    JComboBox<String> cboDeptLeg1;
    JComboBox<String> cboDestLeg1;
    JComboBox<String> cboSeatType;
    JLabel lblDeptLeg2;
    JLabel lblDestLeg2;
    JComboBox<String> cboDeptLeg2;
    JComboBox<String> cboDestLeg2;
    JCheckBox chkbxInsurance;
    JButton btnBookFlights;
    JButton btnClear;
    JButton btnLogout;
    String defaultItem = "--Select Airport--";

    public GUICustomerScreen() {
        setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblHello = new JLabel("<html>Hello " + firstName + "<br>" + lastName + "</html>");
        lblHello.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Black", Font.ITALIC, 14));
        lblHello.setBounds(260, 25, 107, 44);
        add(lblHello);

        rdbtnOneWay = new JRadioButton("One Way");
        rdbtnOneWay.setSelected(true);
        rdbtnOneWay.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Black", Font.ITALIC, 11));
        rdbtnOneWay.setBounds(88, 113, 109, 23);
        add(rdbtnOneWay);
        // login.btnOk.addActionListener(event);

        rdbtnReturnsecondLeg = new JRadioButton("Return/Second Leg");
        rdbtnReturnsecondLeg.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Black", Font.ITALIC, 11));
        rdbtnReturnsecondLeg.setBounds(199, 113, 143, 23);
        add(rdbtnReturnsecondLeg);

        group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(rdbtnOneWay);
        group.add(rdbtnReturnsecondLeg);

        JLabel lblDeparture = new JLabel("Departure ");
        lblDeparture.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Black", Font.ITALIC, 11));
        lblDeparture.setBounds(40, 146, 67, 14);
        add(lblDeparture);

        JLabel lblArrival = new JLabel("Destination");
        lblArrival.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Black", Font.ITALIC, 11));
        lblArrival.setBounds(154, 146, 67, 14);
        add(lblArrival);

        JLabel lblSeatType = new JLabel("Seat Type");
        lblSeatType.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Black", Font.ITALIC, 11));
        lblSeatType.setBounds(260, 146, 67, 14);
        add(lblSeatType);

        cboDeptLeg1 = new JComboBox<String>();
        cboDeptLeg1.setMaximumRowCount(10);
        cboDeptLeg1.setBounds(40, 171, 104, 20);
        cboDeptLeg1.removeAllItems();
        cboDeptLeg1.addItem(defaultItem);
        cboDeptLeg1.addItem("Dublin");
        cboDeptLeg1.addItem("Luton");
        cboDeptLeg1.addItem("Sligo");
        add(cboDeptLeg1);

        cboDestLeg1 = new JComboBox<String>();
        cboDestLeg1.setBounds(154, 171, 96, 20);
        add(cboDestLeg1);

        cboSeatType = new JComboBox<String>();
        cboSeatType.setBounds(260, 171, 82, 20);
        add(cboSeatType);

        lblDeptLeg2 = new JLabel("Departure ");
        lblDeptLeg2.setEnabled(false);
        lblDeptLeg2.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Black", Font.ITALIC, 11));
        lblDeptLeg2.setBounds(40, 202, 67, 14);
        add(lblDeptLeg2);

        lblDestLeg2 = new JLabel("Destination");
        lblDestLeg2.setEnabled(false);
        lblDestLeg2.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Black", Font.ITALIC, 11));
        lblDestLeg2.setBounds(154, 202, 67, 14);
        add(lblDestLeg2);

        cboDeptLeg2 = new JComboBox<String>();
        cboDeptLeg2.setEnabled(false);
        cboDeptLeg2.setBounds(40, 227, 104, 20);
        add(cboDeptLeg2);

        cboDestLeg2 = new JComboBox<String>();
        cboDestLeg2.setEnabled(false);
        cboDestLeg2.setBounds(154, 227, 96, 20);
        add(cboDestLeg2);

        chkbxInsurance = new JCheckBox("Would you like to purchase insurance?");
        chkbxInsurance.setSelected(true);
        chkbxInsurance.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Black", Font.ITALIC, 11));
        chkbxInsurance.setBounds(40, 254, 250, 23);
        add(chkbxInsurance);

        btnBookFlights = new JButton("Book Flight(s)");
        btnBookFlights.setBounds(40, 331, 104, 23);
        add(btnBookFlights);

        btnClear = new JButton("Clear");
        btnClear.setBounds(154, 331, 106, 23);
        add(btnClear);

        btnLogout = new JButton("Logout");
        btnLogout.setBounds(270, 331, 97, 23);
        add(btnLogout);

    }
}
```

Comment: These guys `JFrame mainGUI = gui.frame;` etc... are called **before** the GUIMainEvent constructor is called, and so gui is null at this time. **Declare** the fields in the class but **fill** the fields in the constructor which will be after you have received a valid object for the gui variable.

Comment: I myself would re-design the program, and have each sub-view be more self-sufficient and not connected as you're doing it. Also, as a side recommendation, I try to avoid `null` layouts like the plague as they're a sign of newbie code since the more experience you have with them, the more you realize their dangers and difficulties. They are a royal witch to debug and enhance for instance.

Comment: Completely forgot about that, thanks. How would you make them more self-sufficient? Should the logic for each class be in each class?

Comment: No, the logic should be part of the model, but large subsections of code might have independent Model-View-Controller blocks.